# Formatting XQuery onto multiple lines using Zorba and Eclipse

Tags: xml, xquery

I am using Eclipse and Zorba to write XQuery.  I am trying to get my results on multiple lines, but all I get is one line.  I am writing a simple query

```
for $n in doc("BookstoreQ.xml")//Last_Name
return $n
```

And my output is:

```
e.g. (<Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name><Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name><Last_Name>Garcia-Molina</Last_Name><Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name><Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>)
```

How can I get:

```
<Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name>
<Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
<Last_Name>Garcia-Molina</Last_Name>
<Last_Name>Ullman</Last_Name>
<Last_Name>Widom</Last_Name>
```

It is driving me insane.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see how to turn on indentation:

[Zorba XQuery Get started](http://www.xquery.me/tutorial_xquery_get_started/get_tutorial_page/run_your_first_xquery_module)